# PHP Script to fetch new row from mysql on every script execution

Tags: php, mysqli, row

I have a simple my-sql table:

```
+----+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| id | Name    | Father    | National   | Value     |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Daniel  | David    | American    |         0 |
|  2 | Rebbeka | Craig    | American    |         0 |
|  3 | Robert  | John     | American    |         0 |
|  4 | Arjun   | Daneil   | Indian      |         0 |
|  5 | Ana     | Peter    | British     |         0 |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I need to a php-script to query and fetch new single row every time it is executed. It may be based on ID.

About code/framework, i am using simple php5 with mysql on ubuntu server.

This is my code, the probelem is that it outputs whole of the Name,Father columns every time on call, i just want to print a single row everytime it is executed. and on every php script execution a new row should be printed based on id in ascending order.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','database');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "Name:" . $row['name'] . " " . "Father's Name:" . $row['father'];
        echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Every help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tryied anything? What database are you using? Any framework?

Comment: Atleast try something and post question ..

Comment: i think before you edit your question you should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: :D You just updated it ... Now i have answered it according to the last edit ... :) hope you like it

Comment: i will need the 2 way please.

Answer (score 0):

the below code will help you get the output.
from next time when you ask any question pls add your code.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "SELECT * FROM `emp` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//display information:
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo $row["name"].$row["Father"].$row["National"].$row["Value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have no much details of what type of **code/framework** you have I am giving you a answer on the basis of what I understand

There will be two ways I can think of to fetch the data

### 1.

Change the Table Structure and add one more column called `lastFetched` and every-time you fetch the row update the particular row by `1` and else everything else to `0` so that next time when you fetch the row you already know which is the last row fetched by you. and you can do an increment to it.

### 2.

On the page you are fetching the result would have a hidden input where you can store the last data number letz say first time it is `0` when page loads

then your query will be

```
SELECT * from <tablename> LIMIT 0,1
```

and increase the value of the hidden input to +1
so next time you fetch the result will gives the query

```
SELECT * from <tablename> LIMIT 1,2
```

Comment: How can i do that in php5 please?

Comment: Which one would you like to go with 1 or 2

Comment: I am adding a new answer for that

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion we had in the comments I came to a conclusion that you are looking for this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pullNextRecord'))
{
    $whtrec=$_POST['whatrecord'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','database');
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table LIMIT $whtrec, ++$whtrec");
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='whatrecord' value=".$whtrec." />";
    echo "<th>Name</th><th>Fathers Name</th></tr><tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<td>$row['name']</td><td>$row['father']</td>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="pullNextRecord" />
```